# Unique count through Pivot

Tags: excel, count, pivot, excel-2007, unique

I need to count the unique occurrences of brands in a database.

My database looks like that (see below "database"): country in column A and trademarks in column B (here A, B or C). Some brands are duplicated and mentioned twice in one country. I need one list with the count of unique brands per country (see below "results needed"). Excel 2007 does not include "Count unique" in the pivot functions. Any idea how to do that?

**Database**

```
Afghanistan  A
Albania      B
Albania      B
Albania      A
Albania      C
Albania      D
Algeria      A
Algeria      A
Algeria      B
Algeria      C
```

**Results needed**

```
Count of unique brands
Afghanistan   1
Albania       4
Algeria       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Data > Remove Duplicates` before creating the pivot table.